# Can ADFS 2.0 authentication have username@domain.com format?

Tags: authentication, adfs2.0

ADFS 2.0 auth has domain\username and password format(i.e. typical windows login format). Can we have username@domain.com format?(e.g. for sharepoint online)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of!

AD allows authentication through the pre Windows 2000 sAMAccountName e.g. JoeBloggs and the "new" UPN - JoeBloggs@domain.com. The problem is that these UPN suffixes have to be pre-configured.

So in a closed environment it will work but if every man and his dog can authenticate e.g. @gmail, @hotmail, @yahoo etc. - it's not really practical.